# How to use import_transform of the bulk loader tool?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

On data import I should apply the following transformation:

```
if value:
    return hashlib.sha512(value + salt).hexdigest()
```

How can I use that with import_transform?

Comment: Note that this _isn't_ a secure way to hash passwords (it's marginally better than a plain hash, but you should be using something like PBKDF2, or at the very least an iterated HMAC).

Comment: @NickJohnson, thank you, but it is not for passwords ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following helped:

```
import_transform: "lambda x: hashlib.sha512(x.encode('utf-8') + 'actual_salt_value').hexdigest()"
```

Upd. the following code handles the case, when field is missed in the upload file:

```
import_transform: "lambda x: None if x is None or x=='' else hashlib.sha512(x.encode('utf-8') + 'actual_salt_value').hexdigest()"
```